# MS graph API for place always returning properties like "Building","Floor" as null

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

Hi I'm using the following API to fetch the resource mailbox details.

```
 var place = await graphClient.Places["roomaddress@microsoft.com"]
.Request()
.GetAsync();
```

But Building, floor, etc such properties are always null. even it has value in the exchange server. Those values ​​can be obtained using the PowerShell command.

```
 Get-Place -Identity "roomaddress@microsoft.com"
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Sumith, Not sure this is a duplicate issue that we worked earlier. Still i will go ahead and answer it. 

(1) You can use the set-place Exchange PowerShell cmdlet to set the values for your exchange online mailbox and update its metadata info. Here is the related documentation link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-place?view=exchange-ps

(2) Then, use Graph API SDK or MS Graph Explorer and make the API call, it returns the values.

(If the reply was helpful please don't forget to upvote or accept as answer, thank you)

Comment: Moving this to answer - so it can be useful to others; consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is a duplicate issue that we worked earlier. Still i will go ahead and answer it.

(1) You can use the set-place Exchange PowerShell cmdlet to set the values for your exchange online mailbox and update its metadata info. Here is the related [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-place?view=exchange-ps)

(2) Then, use Graph API SDK or MS Graph Explorer and make the API call, it returns the values.